# Start wildfly as service

Tags: server, ssh, services

I installed wildfly on an ubuntu on a EC2 VM. I connect to the server via SSH and start the server with:

```
./standalone.sh --server-config=standalone-full.xml
```

This works fine until I terminate the SSH connection. How can I start this as service so it stays active after closing the SSH connection. Did not find any working guide about that. Is there any easy way to do that?

Comment: try this: `./standalone.sh --server-config=standalone-full.xml & disown`

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/285015/3644902

Comment: Have a look at this script: https://gist.github.com/sukharevd/6087988

Answer (score 1):

[There is a script to do this](https://gist.github.com/sukharevd/6087988).

If you want to have a service available: from the script I would assume you need to do this:

```
WILDFLY_DIR=$INSTALL_DIR/wildfly
INSTALL_DIR=/opt
WILDFLY_USER="wildfly"
WILDFLY_SERVICE="wildfly"
```

....

```
echo "Registrating Wildfly as service..."
# if Debian-like distribution
if [ -r /lib/lsb/init-functions ]; then
    cp $WILDFLY_DIR/bin/init.d/wildfly-init-debian.sh /etc/init.d/$WILDFLY_SERVICE
    sed -i -e 's,NAME=wildfly,NAME='$WILDFLY_SERVICE',g' /etc/init.d/$WILDFLY_SERVICE
    WILDFLY_SERVICE_CONF=/etc/default/$WILDFLY_SERVICE
fi
```

Ie. copy  `/opt/wildfly/bin/init.d/wildfly-init-debian.sh` over to `/etc/init.d/wildfire`. Change the `/etc/init.d/wildfire` and change the NAME to `wildfly` and the part of the script a bit down explains how to start it as a service so you could make your own service from it.